# Unable to reference to com.facebook.widget.LikeView android

Tags: android, facebook-like, facebook-sdk-3.1

i'm trying to implement the facebook like button to my android app and i used this code:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LikeView
    android:id="@+id/LikeView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</com.facebook.widget.LikeView>
```

and i get this error:

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - com.facebook.widget.LikeView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
>   See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
>   Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse
>
> > java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
> >         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(    at
> >     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(    at
> >     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(    at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(    at
> >     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(    at
> >     com.facebook.widget.LikeView.parseAttributes(LikeView.java:382)
> >         at com.facebook.widget.LikeView.(LikeView.java:266)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at
> >     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at
> >     com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:442)
> >         at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:194)
> >         at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
> >         at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
> >         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
> >         at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
> >         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
> >         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
> >         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)

the facebook sdk is set correctly to the project and the "LikeView" activity is present under facebook.widget and I'm using the login button without any problems.
Is there anyone who have an idea about this problem.

Comment: it is just the ide graphical editor. Try to run it

Comment: i just tried it but nothing appears.

Comment: Try the solution mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/43310939/976141.