# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in LikeView

Tags: android

I am working with facebook like button, but I am facing this problem in my app. First, when I clicked on likebutton, nothing happened and app closed, then second time it throws an exception error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.widget.LikeView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mine4.pantryrecipes-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.mine4.pantryrecipes-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at com.example.mine4.pantryrecipes.BeefR1.onCreate(BeefR1.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is my likeview code in XML.

```
 <com.facebook.widget.LikeView
                android:id="@+id/like_view"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

And here is my manifist code for facebook sharing.

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
<provider
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider760413047410118"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true" />

<meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="760413047410118"/>
```

I am not getting my problem please tell me for that and here is `onCreate` method.

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
likeView.setObjectIdAndType( "https://www.facebook.com/junaidsaif786",
                LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
```

Comment: You are using eclipse or android studio ?

Comment: android studio I am using

Comment: please try answer and one link also which describes you to all steps to integrate like button in android

Comment: I tried it now its not working on likeView and share button. when I add likeview it suddenly create execption.  Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:

Comment: have you included facebook sdk properly because it contains all classes of facebook.

Comment: yes by my knowledge I did it. but maybe I made some mistake. So please suggest me some tips for that. I am stuck

Comment: the link you sent I followed it but not working

Comment: Check edited answer with some code like button.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Removed `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'` from the dependencies in gradle
2. Synced it
3. Added the same dependency again
4. Again Synced it

can take help from this link

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-add-facebook-like-button-in-android-applications/

Use as:

```
 <com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
            android:id="@+id/like_view"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
```

Hope, it will help you!!

Comment: this worked because of com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView. Facebook document has a class com.facebook.widget.LikeView which does not work. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours on the same problem. Finally found solution by changing package name of LikeView in .xml file. Change `com.facebook.widget.LikeView` class in xml file to

`com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView`.

For your reference, I used the following facebook sdk in my build.gradle

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
```